# Laravel Lighthouse GraphQL array to string error

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

Why is it that in the Lighthouse Docs, upload directive is listed and explained, but trying to use it in the schema:

```
scalar Upload @scalar(class: "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Types\\Scalars\\Upload")


extend type Mutation {
    createImageList(
        id: ID!
        category_id: String!
        image_path: [Upload!]! @upload(disk: "public", path: "images/gallery", public: true)
        thumbnail: String!
        label: String
        description: String
        tags: JSON
        favorite_count: Int
    ): GalleryImageList @upsert
}
```

returns:

```
"debugMessage": "No directive found for upload"
```

I later checked the changelog of Lighthouse, and found out that upload directive was added in v5.6.
Using
`composer require nuwave/lighthouse`
added v5.58 of Lighthouse instead, which is an unexpected behavior.

I finally used:
`composer require nuwave/lighthouse dev-master`
Which updated Lighthouse to the latest version v5.68+

Now, I got a new error:

```
"debugMessage": "Array to string conversion",
            "message": "Internal server error"
```

I hope to find a way to upload files using upload directive soon.

Comment: create a custom mutation for this

Comment: I already tried a custom mutation, and did an import in the schema: 
```scalar Upload @scalar(class: "App\\GraphQL\\Mutations\\Upload")```
But laravel could not find the class. How do I make it work?

Comment: Now, it can see the class.
I got the below error:
```"message": "Variable \"$image_path\" got invalid value [{},{},{}]; Expected type Upload; Could not get uploaded file, be sure to conform to GraphQL multipart request specification: https:\/\/github.com\/jaydenseric\/graphql-multipart-request-spec Instead got: [{},{},{}]",
           ```

This is same error I got when I changed the field type from 
```[Upload!]! to Upload!```

Comment: **Update**
I found out that using the field type: ```[Upload!]!``` actually works, for the images were uploaded to the folder specified in the public drive, although it still gives the below error, and the database is not updated as stated in the mutation:
```debugMessage: "Array to string conversion"```

Comment: You should not use `[Upload!]!` but just `Upload!` I believe.

Comment: I said ealier, ```Upload!``` throws error and doesn't save the images to the folder, whereas ```[Upload!]!``` does save images to the folder, but still throws error, because the file array is being converted to string, which is the image_path type field.

I just need to find a way to get the generated image name (has different name from the uploaded file name), and then store it in the database.

Comment: From my observation ```@upload(disk: "public", path: "images/gallery", public: true)``` works just fine, because it is responsible for the successful file upload.
However, the ```Upload``` class is not fetching the saved image names, leading to the general failure of the mutation to database.

I guess a custom Upload class is needed to do the desired job. How do I achieve this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

==== SOLVED ====
Added json cast to image_path field, and wolla, it worked! It returned the following, with the 3 images uploaded, and the generated file names saved to database.
`["images\/gallery\/LimSUx2xO9yvLYZg0Pl8L05MRcFISnLTprx1hOUq.jpg","images\/gallery\/3k8NSpOJFu6oYxplMW7Bik2j12mmVsHcOK1ZM4qJ.jpg","images\/gallery\/lRnpeAquOItYPZ35jPL2rBBDojWdxM2JkKosJ7Su.jpg"]`

I am still testing the url of the uploaded image on the api:

`localhost/images/gallery/LimSUx2xO9yvLYZg0Pl8L05MRcFISnLTprx1hOUq.jpg`

Returns:
`404 Not Found`

Comment: File path now works, after I did this:

```php artisan storage:link```

Files are available publicly at:

```hhtp://localhost/storage/images/gallery/3k8NSpOJFu6oYxplMW7Bik2j12mmVsHcOK1ZM4qJ.jpg```